# shortcut link to specific subject

Tags: support, short-links

I follow code::blocks a lot but every time I want to visit the latest questions page, I need to push

> Tags -> enter "codeblocks" string and -> push again on codeblocks

I know it is only 2 clicks and like 6 char, but if you do it plenty, it becomes pretty cumbersome.

Is there an easy way of making shortcut from profile page to go to specific subject?

Comment: You mean like [tag:codeblocks]? I think you want favourite tags.

Comment: favourite tags, huh? ah, and btw thanks for editing my post, you perfectly proved my point :)